# Correct path in PrimeFaces View

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, path, relative-path

I'm using PrimeFaces version 5.2 and Glassfish as server to deploy my results.
I've coded a short example in order to download a file from the server and I'm getting problems showing the GIF image related to a progress bar.

The problem itself is that I can't find the correct path to the image. My folder structure looks like this image:

[image: Image_1: Project Structure]

I'm going to give you more details in the next images you can see below:

This image shows you the xhtml fragment related to the path, in this case:

> **"images/ajaxloadingbar.gif"**

You can see the GIF is not properly displayed, and the other code appended is the html generated and presented by `Inspect element` option of Chrome Web browser.

[image: Image_2: Wrong path first try]

I noticed that I achieve my goal removing `javax.faces.resource` and the last `xhtml` extension (See 3rd image).

[image: Image_3: Desired Results]

Knowing this behavior I tried some variants in the image path and I'm still struggling with this issue. The following are some of those paths I tried without luck.

[image: Image_4: Path not recognized]

> `Unable to find or serve resource, images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, /images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, ../../images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, ../images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, Pack_Encrypt/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, /Pack_Encrypt/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`
>
> `Unable to find or serve resource, /WebContent/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.`

I really appreciate any help or idea regarding this tricky path. I would like to use a relative path rather than an absolute path.

Kind regards,
Luis A.

Comment: @BalusC,

  I made my research before posting my question. I performed some searches like: 

1- Primefaces problem with image path

2 - Path image in PrimeFaces (Actually you marked one of those questions as [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295652/how-to-get-image-through-image-path-in-primefaces-using-grphicaimage-tag). )
<br/>
I didn't try with **Facelets Templates** because those terms are completely new to me.

Please don't downvote my question because of this. This question can help people unfamiliar with the terms used above.

Comment: Just learn JSF by Oracle's own Java EE tutorial or a real book. All terms you need to know (and more ..) are covered in there. I didn't downvote, I just closed as duplicate, so the search engine can now find new keywords in your question and associate it with the existing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move folder "images" into new folder "resources".

Full path should be "...\WebContent\resources\images"

Check out the following page:

[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)